# Android llow to replace app programmatically

Tags: android

I get "app already exist" every time when I tried to install it.  I need to uninstall first.

How I can allow to replace app programmatically..

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Do you want update application?

Answer (score 1):

Make any change in you code, add a comment or so then try to run again.

Answer (score 0):

You may use *Intent.ACTION_UNINSTALL_PACKAGE* flag

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_UNINSTALL_PACKAGE, uri);
```

And than call install intent.